# Retrieving data list from Firebase [Swift]

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I'm trying to get a String array with the list of all usernames, but for some reason my code isn't working. Output should be [sean, yuh]

```
Database.database().reference().child("usernames").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in
        
  for child in snapshot.children {
     let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            
     let uid = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "username")
            
        self.array.append(uid1)
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Totally off topic and I see there's an accepted answer but consider using the firebase users uid as their uid instead of rolling something custom. It makes like a lot simpler down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uid1` is not declared in the code you shared, and definitely not the value of the username property in the JSON. In addition, you'll want to get the `value` of the child snapshot. So combines:

```
Database.database().reference().child("usernames").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            
    let uid = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "username")      
      self.array.append(uid.value)
    }
  }
```